# Issue with running jNotify in linux (CentOS 5.4)

Tags: java, centos5, jnotify

I'm trying to setup jnotify in a centos 5.4 (64 bit) box to monitor directories for file change. I followed the instruction by putting the libjnotify.so in java library path. Here's my entry

```
java -Xms64m -Xmx2048m -Djava.library.path=. -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar test-1.1.0.jar
```

When I try to execute it, I'm getting the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /root/testprocessor/libjnotify.so: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.12' not found (required by /root/testprocessor/libjnotify.so)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1778)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1703)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
        at net.contentobjects.jnotify.linux.JNotify_linux.(Unknown Source)
        at net.contentobjects.jnotify.linux.JNotifyAdapterLinux.(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
        at net.contentobjects.jnotify.JNotify.(Unknown Source)
```

The error certainly points to missing library 'GLIBC_2.12' in CentOS. Just wanted to know if anyone faced similar issues ?

Any pointer on this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, resolved it with the help of a CentOS geek. Just thought of sharing the answer if anyone encounters a similar issue.

1. You can upgrade your CentOS version to 6.* to get the GCLIB_2.12 and above.
2. If you are in my situation where version upgrade is not an option, you need create a **libjnotify.so** and remove the dependency on **GCLIB_2.12**. Here's what you need to do by checking out jNotify source code.

```
cd ~/compile
mkdir jnotify
cd jnotify
unzip ~/downloads/jnotify-lib-0.94.zip
mkdir src
cd src
unzip ../jnotify-native-linux-0.94-src.zip
cd Release
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/include/:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/include/linux/
make
```

This will generated **libjnotify.so** , copy it to you java library path and restart the jar file. It should resolve the issue.