# Error using Play Framework: Cannot load the JNotify native library; Possible cause: can't load IA 32-bit .so on a ARM-bit platform))

Tags: playframework, arm, raspberry-pi, playframework-2.3, jnotify

I'm running a play framework application on a Rapsberry Pi (so ARM) and I'm getting the following error:

`Cannot load the JNotify native library (/usr/lib/libjnotify.so: /usr/lib/libjnotify.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (Possible cause: can't load IA 32-bit .so on a ARM-bit platform))
Play will check file changes for each request, so expect degraded reloading performace.`

I read [here](https://buddhacodes.wordpress.com/2013/02/11/jnotify-native-library-for-play/) that I have to install the jnotify library. So I downloaded it from Source Forge and put the `libjnotify.so` in /urs/lib/. Do I need to do any further steps than just copying the library?

Even after a reboot the error message remains. I also changed the owner and group of the library to root (as all other libraries had these rights). Giving every user all rights does help neither.

Moreover, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15039362/error-starting-fresh-play-2-1-project). The answer suggests to remove all whitespace from the path. But in my case there is no directory and no file having any whitespace in it's name.

Does anybody know why the Play Framework still cpmplains about the missing library?
I'm looking forward to your answers, thanks :)

Comment: My money's on that error message being right about it being an IA-32 library. Remember that the world suffers from "everything is an x86" disease, so unless precompiled binaries are explicitly labelled as being for ARM, assume they're not, and that you're going to have to build the thing from source.

Comment: Alright, did I understood you right, that I have to build the jnotify library on my own?
How do I do that?
The [download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jnotify/files/jnotify/jnotify-0.94/) contains also a folder called 'jnotify-native-linux'. Within this folder are files written in C, two header files and many more.

Comment: Following [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12649016/4425803) I get the following error when making jnotify:
'In file included from ../net_contentobjects_jnotify_linux_JNotify_linux.c:43:0:
../inotify-syscalls.h:35:0: error: "__NR_inotify_init" redefined [-Werror]
/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/asm/unistd.h:344:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
....'

Comment: Judging by the article linked from [this thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/jnotify/discussion/515553/thread/e0b6ab15), getting it building for ARM looks fiddly but possible.

Comment: OK, thanks. This solution is definitely too unintelligible for me.